SQL Developer app crashes
I have downloaded SQL developer on my Mac running OS Sonoma 14.1.2 but as soon as i launch it it quits unexpectedly. I have installed latest JDK 11. I don't seem to find the reason for its crash. I executed sqldeveloper.sh in terminal and i encountered following error
line 16: [: missing `]'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

